# Property changes on module twins

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Would a change in a reported property in a module on IoT Edge generate an event that can be 'observed' by an application via IoT Hub APIs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IoT Hub Service API (REST) to ["poll" the current state of your module twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/digitaltwinmodelrepositoryservice/service/getmoduletwin).

If you want to be notified in real time, you can [setup a route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#non-telemetry-events) to have your twin change events be sent to Blob storage, Event Hub, Service bus…

Answer (score -1):

Polling and setting up a route are definitively the 2 ways to go on the back-end side of things. You can also find more details on back-end operations in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#back-end-operations).